# show div if sibling doesn't have a certain class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have two divs, one with the class "***d-none***":

```html
    <div class="inexistente">
      Ainda não existem documentos adicionados 
    </div>
     <div class="existentes d-none"></div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to hide the other
with the "div.existentes" when it doesn't have "***.d-none***" anymore.

I've tried the selectors below:

```css
existentes:not(.d-none) + .inexistente {
    display:none;
}
```

```css
existentes:not(.d-none) ~ .inexistente {
    display:none;
}
```

But both didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to style an element according to "future elements". If you can change the HTML order of the two, everything works.

```css
.existentes:not(.d-none) ~ .inexistente{
display:none
}
```

```html
<div class="existentes"></div>
<div class="inexistente">
      Ainda não existem documentos adicionados 
    </div>
```